# Queryset for ManyToMany relation in Django

Tags: python, django

I can't understand how I should get queryset for groups, that contains user, I've tried _set, prefetch_select, but still without result.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    Member_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Member', related_name="Member_list")

class Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

I need get all Groups associated with that user, like 
Groups where Member.objects.filter(user==request.user)

Im trying:

```
user = request.user
groups = user.group_set.all() # empty list :(
member = user.member_set.all() # works currectly, returns my 1 test group
```

Comment: Try to use ``user.member_list_set.all()`` (it's because of ``related_name`` option)

Comment: @erthalion error: 'User' object has no attribute 'member_list_set'

Comment: Can you show ``user.__dict__`` ?

Comment: @erthalion If i did it correct: {'_setupfunc': <function <lambda> at 0x0346F2F0>, '_wrapped': <User: temp>}

Comment: Ouch, what about ``user._wrapped.__dict__`` ?)

Comment: @erthalion I del password, was too long for comment: {'username': u'temp', 'first_name': u'test', 'last_name': u'test', 'is_active': True, 'max_quests_slots': 4, 'sex': u'man', '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x03CABD10>, 'birthday': datetime.date(1989, 5, 23), 'email': u'asdf@asdf.sd', 'is_superuser': True, 'is_staff': True, 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 17, 2, 18, 52, 165000, tzinfo=<UTC>),  'is_removed': False, 'password': , 'id': 2, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 14, 1, 51, 52, tzinfo=<UTC>)}

Comment: try ``dir(user)`` - this function must show you the object attrs, include a reverse field.

Comment: @erthalion it has uiverse_set attr, but it returns empty list. May be i get why it happends, i have lots of relations, like user can adds photo with Foreignkey creator(user) and ForeignKey group. And it like curcle, when i use universe_set it goes on wrong way. Why we should add related name everywhere, but cant use it. :( Looks like i need pure SQL, not ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just create your base. Create group, user and connect them:

```
u = User.objects.create(name='user')
g = Group.objects.create()
m = Member.objects.create(group=g, user=u)
```

After this i can get user groups like this:

```
u.Member_list.all()
# output: [<Group: Group object>]
```

My base:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4)


class Group(models.Model):
    Member_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Member', related_name="Member_list")


class Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```